# kill-ring-save vs. clipboard-kill-ring-save

Tags: emacs, ubuntu-12.04, emacs23

In the menu-bar of Emacs-23 under [Edit] there is Cut, Copy, Paste which are all explicit clipboard related commands ; the traditional <kbd>C-w</kbd>, <kbd>M-w</kbd>, <kbd>C-y</kbd> are no longer offered, and these no longer have an effect relevant to X.

What is the cleanest way to make the traditional commands clipboard-aware? It seems there must be some more systematic way than just redefining everything. <kbd>C-h C-n</kbd> did not help me.

Is it intended to hide the traditional command from users?

Edit: Or at least: a command to "synchronize" with the clipboard.

Comment: I looked at this a while ago and couldn't find anything other than redefining. This was one of the factors in my switch to gVim.

Comment: @Garry Cairns: Please have a look at the answer below.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer @false, although I'm afraid I'm too ingrained in working with gVim to switch back now. I've truly gone to the dark side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

X has two "clipboards": the primary selection, and the clipboard.  Emacs 23 uses the primary selection by default, but it seems you want the clipboard.  You can enable this with the following in your `.emacs`:

```
(setq x-select-enable-clipboard t)
```

This setting changed in Emacs 24 to use the clipboard by default.  See also: http://emacswiki.org/emacs/CopyAndPaste

Comment: Thanks! This variable can be customized too!